# App Store Optimization: Individual localization for English (U.S.), Australia, Canada and U.K.?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, internationalization

I have an iOS app that is **available in all territories** and its **primary language is set to English (U.S.)**. I've also created store listings for Australia, Canada and U.K., but I'm using the same localization as for the primary language, since I only have localizations with American spelling.

What happens if I remove the **redundant App Store localizations** for U.K., Australia and Canada? Would customers from the U.K., Australia and Canada still get the primary language's App Store Information or would it result in a negative impact on **App Store Optimization**?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I was tempted to close this as too broad, but I see you’ve gotten the association bonus. Would you mind removing the sub questions and making the 1-2-3 points and then asking one main question at the end of the points?

Answer (score 1):

After almost a year of observation, it appears that it **does not have a negative impact on ASO**.

This is because my primary language **English (U.S.) is used for Australia, Canada and U.K. as well.**

So the other localizations were redundant, given that they were a copy of English (U.S.) anyway.

Comment: What if you select English (U.K.) as the default language?